# JClouds not able to get the list of images

Tags: openstack, jclouds

I have used the code below:

```
    Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(
            new SshjSshClientModule());

    ContextBuilder builder = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider).endpoint(endpoint)
            .credentials(identity, credential)
            .modules(modules);

    System.out.printf(">> initializing %s%n", builder.getApiMetadata());

 ComputeService compute = builder.buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class).getComputeService();
```

System.out.println(compute1.listImages());

but I am getting the following error message.........

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 787
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.DeserializationConstructorAndReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$DeserializeIntoParameterizedConstructor.read(DeserializationConstructorAndReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:181)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$IterableTypeAdapter.readAndBuild(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:92)

The code was working... before...

Answer (score 0):

You've definitely hit a bug somewhere between the version of jclouds you're using and whatever version of whatever cloud you're using. We'll need more information to fix this. Please go through the instruction on how to [Report a Bug](http://jclouds.apache.org/reference/report-a-bug/) to Apache jclouds.